# how to send the selected row values from jqGrid to server?

Tags: jqgrid, multi-select

I have a grid with multiselect option true...so when I multiselected the rows and click on the button say "Release"
it should send those rows to server ...Can any one point me towards right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Inside of `onSelectRow` event handler (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_events) you receive the array of ids of selected rows as a parameter. With respect of `getRowData(ids[i])` (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) you can get full data from the i-th selected row. Then you can construct the from all the data a data which you want to send to server and use [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to send the data to the server.